# JavaScriptでブラウザキャッシュを削除したい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptで「ブラウザキャッシュを削除」するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

意図としては「クリックしたらブラウザキャッシュを削除」みたいな感じにしたいです

Comment: 恐らく不可能です。HTTPヘッダのCache-Controlを適切に設定する、URLにランダムなパラメータを割り当てるなどでキャッシュを無効化できるはずです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webページの閲覧者のファイルを勝手に削除できないのと同様、
原理的に不可能です。

Answer (score 2):

対象のURLが分かっていて同一オリジン内であればキャッシュを更新することは可能です。

jQuery を使っています。

```javascript
var reload = function(url) {
    var ifm;
    try {
        ifm = $('<iframe width="1" height="1" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" style="position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px">')
            .attr('src', url)
            .one('load', function() {
                if (this.contentDocument) {
                    this.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
                    ifm.one('load', function() {
                        ifm.remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    ifm.remove();
                }
            })
            .appendTo('body');
    } catch(e) {
        ifm && ifm.remove();
    }
};
```

Comment: `location.reload(true)` の挙動はブラウザによって違うようで、Chromeだと `location.reload()` の引数にかかわらず `If-Modified-Since` が送信されてしまいました。これも送信しないことを望むなら、この方法は使えないかもしれません。